# String matching

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, string

How to match the string "Net        Amount" (between Net and Amount there can be any number of spaces, including zero) with `net amount`?

Spaces between these two words can be any whitespace and exact matching of two string should be there. But Net Amount (first string with spaces) can be part of any string like `Rate Net Amount` or `Rate CommissionNet Amount.`

The match should be **case-insensitive.**

Comment: What do you mean by 'match'? Do you just want to check if a match exists? Do you want the index of the match? Do you want to replace this string with something else?

Comment: @Mark Byers,Sir.. I want to just check if matching is exists ?

Comment: @Harikrishna: Can the match be a substring anywhere in your string or do you want an exact match of the entire string? (PS: instead of answering in comments, it is better to update your question to include the missing information).

Comment: @Harikrishna: Do you want to allow any whitespace (e.g. tabs, newlines) or just spaces?

Comment: @Mark Byers,Yes sir...Spaces between these two words can be whitespace and exact matching should be there not substring..

Comment: @Harikrishna: I think I have just one more question: Is it required that there is at least one whitespace character between Net and Amount, or should the input "NetAmount" also match?

Comment: @Mark Byers,Yes Sir..If there is no any space like NetAmount then also it should be matched...

Comment: @Harikrishna: Sorry.... Hun1Ahpu's post made me think of another question: does capitalization matter?

Comment: @Mark Byers,Sir..If Case is different, then also matching should bed done.And if there is extra whitespace at the beginning and/or the end of the line, such as "Net Amount\n, it should be matched.

Comment: @Harikrishna: I've updated your question based on your comments. I hope that I have understood you correctly, if not, please edit the question again.

Comment: @Mark Byers, Sir.. but there is another problem, the string which I want to match with existing string in the file,and I can not change it.It comes from the combobox and like in the combobox there will be Net Amount.And how can I update it with programming ?

Comment: @Harikrishna: Do you mean that you want to create the regular expression dynamically based on user input? You can do that, but be sure to use `Regex.Escape` appropriately. This is quite a considerable change from your existing question. I'm not sure whether you should edit this question or just accept the best answer here and start a new question. In future give **a lot** more information about what you want, preferably including example input, expected output, the code that you've tried, and what output you get. It shouldn't be necessary to ask so many question clarifications.

Comment: @Mark Byers,Ok sir,Thank you very much sir...But can I remove the space or white space between two words like Net Amount ?

Comment: @Mark Byers, Sir can I remove the all spaces between net and amount words using regex and keep only one space between them ?

Comment: @Harikrishna: Yes. Sounds like you need to use Regex.Replace instead of Match. Try reading the RegularExpressions documentation or tutorials and see if you can work it out yourself first.

Comment: @Mark Byers,ok sir and sir I had upvoted for the answer and again I wanted  to upvoted the answer but votes were decreemented. And now I can not upvote the answer. What the problem can be ?

Comment: @Harikrishna: I don't know. Probably a feature of SO that you can't change your vote again unless I edit my post. This isn't an appropriate place to ask this sort of question. You could ask on meta.stackoverflow.com. But honestly I wouldn't worry about it that much. It's just one vote.

Comment: @Mark Byers,I know you are not worried about that but it is my feeling that I want to give you not only one but lots of upvote so I had asked you such a question that why I can not upvote the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to check if a match exists, use [IsMatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y21t6y4.aspx):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string s = "Net     Amount";
        bool isMatch = Regex.IsMatch(s, @"Net\s*Amount",
                                     RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        Console.WriteLine("isMatch: {0}", isMatch);
    }
}
```

---

Update: In your comments it sounds like the string you want to search for is only known at runtime. You could try building the regular expression dynamically, for example something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string input = "Net     Amount";
        string needle = "Net Amount";

        string regex = Regex.Escape(needle).Replace(@"\ ", @"\s*");
        bool isMatch = Regex.IsMatch(input, regex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        Console.WriteLine("isMatch: {0}", isMatch);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Mark Byers,Sir, if we want to match the string like buy-sell and buy/sell then how can we do it ?

Comment: @Harikrishna: This is too far offtopic for this question IMHO. You should create a new question. Remember to include very clear specifications, example inputs, example outputs. Include examples both of when you want the match to succeed, and when you want it to fail. Attempt to solve the problem yourself first, and include your code in the question. Show an example of where and how your code fails.

Answer (score 8):

Use regular expressions. Have a look at the `System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace, namely the `Regex` class:

```
var regex = new RegEx("net(\s+)amount", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
//                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                        pattern
```

The argument string is what is called the regular expression *pattern*. Regular expression patterns describe what strings will match against it. They are expressed with a specialized syntax. Google for `regular expressions` and you should find plenty of information about regexes.

Usage example:

```
bool doesInputMatch = regex.IsMatch("nET      AmoUNT");
//                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                                     test input
```

Comment: Why the downvote? I don't mind, but I'm always willing to better myself (or at least my answers on SO ;).

Comment: I upvoted your answer because it was a good suggestion at the time you posted it and with extra information. But the question has been so heavily edited and clarified that your answer cannot be considered a correct answer with the question's current form. I can imagine that someone reading the question now might downvote it for this reason. Note: I don't think it should downvoted for this reason - I'm just guessing why it might have been.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
Regex.IsMatch(SubjectString, @"net\s*amount", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: +1 For thinking about case-sensitivity. Note though that `RegexOptions.Singleline` is not necessary here - it affects the dot `.` only, and you have no dots in your regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Regular Expression: `Net.*Amount`.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
Regex regex = new Regex("Net.*Amount");
String s = "Net     Amount";
Match m = emailregex.Match(s);

// Now you have information in m about the matching string.
```

Comment: @Anders Abel, Will it match to the All the words which starts with Net ?

Comment: Yes, it will if you use . before the *. The dot matches any character and the star says any number of occurences. If you use "Net +Amount" instead it will only match if there are at least one space (and no other characters) between the words.